# Size(27900) must match the product of shape 1,224,224,3

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am passing tensors from BlazeFace which contain the cropped faces to my custom model for a classification task.
The issue is that the dimensions do not match the input of my custom model which is trained using transfer learning and MobileNetV2. I realized I am trying to resize the cropped faces when they are smaller than the shape of my custom model. What can I do to make the cropped faces fit into the model?

```
Model input shape : [1,224,224,3]
Cropped face : [1,117,68,3]
```

```
        const crop = tf.image.cropAndResize(
          tensorReshaped,
          boxes,
          [0],
          [height, width]
        );
        // Resize cropped faces to [1,224,224,3]
        console.log(crop.shape);
        const prediction = model.predict(crop.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3]));

        if (!prediction || prediction.length === 0) {
          console.log("No prediction available");
          return;
        }
        // Make predictions.
        const preds = prediction.dataSync();
        console.log(preds);
```

Comment: reshape and resize are not the same thing, you should resize your images, not reshape them.

Comment: Alright I will try using tf.image.resizeBilinear() to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to resize the cropped images not reshape them

```
const alignCorners = false;
        // Resize the cropped images to be [1,224,224,3]
        const imageResize = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
          crop,
          [224, 224],
          alignCorners
        );
```